Can anyone help me fix this line system?
I have a game that requires a line system to function, however for the past couple days I have been stuck encountering various bugs and crashes that I might be too dumb to figure out.
When the line first starts everything is fine and everyone moves into place behind them.
APeople* LastPerson = Peoples.Last();
APeople* PreviousPerson = (Peoples.Num() - 2) ? Peoples[Peoples.Num() - 2];
if (PreviousPerson && LastPerson && PreviousPerson->PersonToFollow)
{
        LastPerson->PersonToFollow = Peoples[Peoples.Num() - 2];
                    
        LastPerson->TargetLocation = FVector(
        PreviousPerson->TargetLocation.X,
        PreviousPerson->TargetLocation.Y - LastPerson->Separation,
        PreviousPerson->TargetLocation.Z);
                    
        LastPerson->LastLocation = LastPerson->TargetLocation;
        PeopleController->MoveUp(LastPerson);
}

This is the code for the first people in the line, and the goal is for the other people to simultaneously go to the person they are following last location, which is triggered when the person in the front is destroyed.
for (int32 i = 0; i < GameMode->Peoples.Num(); i++)
{
     if (APeople* CurrentPerson = GameMode->Peoples[i])
     {
         APeopleAIController Controller {Cast Stuff..}
         CurrentPerson->LastLocation = CurrentPerson->GetActorLocation();
         CurrentPerson->TargetLocation = CurrentPerson->PersonToFollow->LastLocation;
         Controller->MoveUp(CurrentPerson)
     }
 }
GameMode->Peoples.Remove(this);
if (GameMode->Spawner)
{
    GameMode->SpawnPerson(Location, Rotation);
} 

The problem is when the first person in destroyed, the line does not move and the newly spawned person tries to replace the people in the array one by one, (So the First Spawned person moves to the same location as the first person, the second spawned person tries to take the second person etc.
I could provide more details if needed.
